# React: How do I create an array from an API object and then select one element randomly for a value?

Tags: arrays, api, reactjs, jsx

Do you know how I could make an array of the x,y coordinates and then select one randomly to place in a value?

```
<g id="lines">
    {data.sites.map((item, i) => {
  let findX = (180 + item.attributes.address.Longitude) * (1552 / 360);
  let findY = (90 - item.attributes.address.Latitude) * (818/ 180);
let randoXY = findX + ',' findY (and randomly selects one of the X, Y values);
       return (
  <path key={i + i + '--'} id={'line' + (i + 1)} class="cls-3" d={'M' + findX + ',' 
+ findY +'L' + randoXY} />
                             )
   })}
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `array` that will contains some random points:

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Then Use `Math.random()` to select a random index, make sure index always lies within the length of the `array` (always multiply the value of `Math.random()` by the length of the array by this way it will never be greater than the length) then convert the value to integer by using `Math.floor()`.

Use this to select random x and y values from the array:

```
<g id="lines">
    {data.sites.map((item, i) => {
        let findX = (180 + item.attributes.address.Longitude) * (1552 / 360);
        let findY = (90 - item.attributes.address.Latitude) * (818/ 180);
        let x = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
        let y = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
        return (
            <path 
                key={i + i + '--'} 
                id={'line' + (i + 1)} 
                class="cls-3" 
                d={`M${findX}, ${findY}L${x},${y}`} />
        )})
    }
</g>
```